# Como fazer para aparecer o anúncio interticial entre uma activity e outra?

Tags: java, android, anúncio

Acho que fiz tudo corretamente, porém o aplicativo pula para a próxima activity sem aparecer nada.

```
public class...

  private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
  private AdView adView01;
  private AdRequest adRequest01;
  private InterstitialAd adInter01;

  onCreate()...

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-6843243039127549/2394454715");
    adView01=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView03);
    adRequest01=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView01.loadAd(adRequest01);
    adInter01=new InterstitialAd(this);
    adInter01.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6843243039127549/3871187910");
    adInter01.loadAd(adRequest01);

    mFirebaseAnalytics=FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

  onClick()...

    case R.id.btnCompras:

      adInter01.show();
      Intent it01 = new Intent(this, MainActivity02.class);
      startActivity(it01);
      break;
```

Penso que pode ser algum problema por estar utilizando o mesmo AdRequest que uso para o banner, mas o banner continua funcionando. **(nessa e na outra activity também)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O aplicativo não acusa nenhum erro, então fica mais difícil para detectar qual a causa do não funcionamento

Site onde peguei informação para colocar anúncio interticial => 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

EDIT 01 ----------------------------------

Fiz o que me indicaram, vejam o código abaixo:

```js
case R.id.btnCompras:

  adInter01.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed(){
      Intent it01 = new Intent(this, MainActivity02.class);
      startActivity(it01);
    }
  });
  break;
```

Porém a tentativa de implementaçao do código, apresentou um erro (não dava para transcrever, por isso a imagem):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem um tutorial perfeitamente explicado no site da AdMob.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira poderia me passar o link?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deva chamar a nova activity quando o anuncio for fechado, usando o AdListener

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
            //aqui tu chama a nova activity
    });
```

Comment: Fiz da forma que indicou, deu erro. Veja no edit

Comment: em vez de This, tente passar o outro contexto, como getApplicationContext()

Comment: Não acusou nenhum erro, porem nenhum anúncio e exibido e nem muda de activity